# passing multiple value from js page to php page

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I want to multiple value from from serice page to php page.I want to pass 'data','albimg','albvideo' to php page.now I caught the error as shown in image.
[image]

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
            data.pagename = "create_album";
            $http.post('js/data/album.php', {action:{"data":data,"albimg":albimg,"albvideo":albvideo}})
                    .success(function (data, status, headers, config)
                    {
                        console.log(status + ' - ' + action);
                        deferred.resolve(action);
                    })
                    .error(function (action, status, headers, config)
                    {
                        deferred.reject(action);
                        console.log('error');
                    });

            return deferred.promise;
php page:
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input",true);
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo $sql="INSERT INTO `$prefix.album` (CONTENT_VALUES,CreatedTime)VALUES('$postdata','$now')";
```

Comment: action is not defined. Above code, action is  not a variable, ( is a property )

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by using param property: like this;

```
var data = {"data":data,"albimg":albimg,"albvideo":albvideo};

$http({ url: "js/data/album.php",    method: "POST",    params: data    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Look to this example:

```
 function PhoneListCtrl($scope, phones) {
      $scope.phones = phones;
      $scope.orderProp = 'age';
    }

    PhoneListCtrl.resolve = {
      phones: function(Phone, $q) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();



 deferred.reject();
    Phone.query(function(successData) {
            deferred.resolve(successData); 
    }, function(errorData) {
            deferred.reject();
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  },
  delay: function($q, $defer) {
    var delay = $q.defer();
    $defer(delay.resolve, 1000);
    return delay.promise;
  }
}
```

I think that you forget add `$defer` to your function. Do you realy need asynchronously? Beacouse if you use `$q` it's that you need it. But if you just want to send data to php file easiest way to use something like this:

```
angular.module('httpExample', [])
.controller('FetchController', ['$scope', '$http', '$templateCache',
  function($scope, $http, $templateCache) {
    $scope.method = 'Post';
    $scope.url = 'http-hello.php';

    $scope.fetch = function() {
      $scope.code = null;
      $scope.response = null;

      $http({method: $scope.method, url: $scope.url, cache: $templateCache}).
        then(function(response) {
          $scope.status = response.status;
          $scope.data = response.data;
        }, function(response) {
          $scope.data = response.data || "Request failed";
          $scope.status = response.status;
      });
    };

    $scope.updateModel = function(method, url) {
      $scope.method = method;
      $scope.url = url;
    };
  }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no action param defined in success callback.

Your code

```
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) // No Action here
    {
        console.log(status + ' - ' + action); // This line gives error
        deferred.resolve(action);
    })
```

Should be

```
.success(function (data, status, headers, config, action) // Add Action here
        {
            console.log(status + ' - ' + action);
            deferred.resolve(action);
        })
```